# How to preseve newline in django posts without using a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using django's forms class along with it's cleaned_data method to get user posts/comments. The problem is that the newlines are not preserved in the cleaned_data field so

```
The firs line of comment.
And the second lines.
```

Ends up being

```
The firs line of comment. And the second lines.
```

Which is not good.

How to avoid this without using a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: Django forms do not automatically strip out HTML tags.

Comment: My question concerns usage of `cleaned_data` method of the forms class.

Comment: Your question states that the `cleaned_data` dictionary doesn't allow harmless tags, when in fact it does. The `clean` method of a field simply tries to coerce the value sent in the POST data into its equivalent Python type. Some fields like `EmailField` or `PositiveSmallIntegerField` will also do validation, but a `CharField` or `TextField` will not strip out tags by itself.

Comment: The docs specifically state that `CharField` will only validate `max_length` or `min_length` if provided, otherwise all inputs are valid: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#charfield

Comment: Are you perhaps using a wysiwyg editor like TinyMCE, which *will* strip out certain types of tags and attributes unless specifically allowed to?

Comment: Sorry Brando. You are right. I revamped my question.

Comment: No worries at all. Just trying to get to the root of the problem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the output of the value held in the field, you just need to use the `linebreaks` or `linebreaksbr` filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks

```
{{ instance.field|linebreaks }}
```

or

```
{{ instance.field|linebreaksbr }}
```

to get the correct formatting without having to use a wysiwyg editor.